# How to infer typed mapValues using lookups in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Similar to:

[How to infer a typed array from a dynamic key array in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775327/how-to-infer-a-typed-array-from-a-dynamic-key-array-in-typescript)

I'm looking to type a generic object which receives a map of arbitrary keys to lookup values, and returns the same keys with typed values (like a typed _.mapValues).

The ability to get a singular typed property from an object is documented and works. With arrays, you need to hardcode overloads to typed tuples, but for objects i'm getting a 'Duplicate string index signature' error.

```
export interface IPerson {
    age: number;
    name: string;
}

const person: IPerson = {
    age: 1,
    name: ""
}

function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, name: K): T[K] {
    return o[name];
}

const a = getProperty(person, 'age');
// a: number

const n = getProperty(person, 'name');
// n: string

function getProperties<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: { [key: string]: K }) {
    const def: { [key: string]: T[K] } = {};
    return Object.entries(keys).reduce((result, [key, value]: [string, K]) => {
        result[key] = getProperty(obj, value);
        return result;
    }, def);
}

const { a2, n2 } = getProperties(person, {
    a2: 'name',
    n2: 'age'
});

// Result:
// {
//     a2: string | number, 
//     n2: string | number
// }

// What I'm looking for:
// {
//     a2: string, 
//     n2: number' 
// }
```

How can this be implemented with typescript?

Comment: Sorry, meant to answer to your comment on the other question but forgot about it. Anyway @jcalz gave the exact answer I was thinking of as well, don't think it can be done better :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a way to optimize/collapse this typing a little bit, but I've got a function prototype for `getProperties` that I believe achieves what you are looking for.

What's missing in your definition is a strong return type definition that links the association between a specific key in the `keys` object and the specific type in the `obj` object. Because this is missing, everything becomes the union of types, which is the behavior you see above.

The function type I've come up with is:

```
function getProperties
    <T, K extends keyof T, U extends { [name: string]: K }>
        (obj: T, keys: U):
            {[V in keyof U]: T[U[V]];
```

The important part here is the return value type: `{[V in keyof U]: T[U[V]]}`

It specifies that for each key `V` in the `keys` object:

1. `V` will be a key in the output object
2. The value type will be a type from the input `obj`, where the type comes from the key given by the value associated with key `V` in `U`.

Answer (score 4):

As long as it's working at runtime, you *can* tell TypeScript how to rename keys using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type RenameKeys<T, KS extends Record<keyof KS, keyof T>> = {[K in keyof KS]: T[KS[K]]};

function getProperties<T, KS extends Record<keyof KS, keyof T>>(
    obj: T,
    keys: KS
): RenameKeys<T, KS> {
    const def = {} as RenameKeys<T, KS>;
    return (Object.entries(keys) as Array<[keyof KS, any]>)
      .reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
        result[key] = getProperty(obj, value);
        return result;
    }, def);
}
```

This should behave as you expect in the type system.  Highlights: the type of `keys` is given a type parameter named `KS`, which is constrained to be `Record<keyof KS, keyof T>`, which more or less means "I don't care what the keys are, but the property types need to be the keys from `T`".  Then, the `RenameKeys<T, KS>` walks through the keys of `KS` and plucks property types out of `T` related to them.

Finally, I needed to do a few type assertions... `def` is `RenameKeys<T, KS>`.  The type of the `value` in `[key, value]` I just made `any`, since it's hard for the type system to verify that `result[key]` will be the right type.  So it's a bit of a fudging of the  implementation type safety... but the caller of `getProperties()` should be happy:

```
const {a2, n2} = getProperties(person, {
  a2: 'name',
  n2: 'age'
});
// a2 is string, n2 is number.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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)