# Types from both keys and values of object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have two sets of string values that I want to map from one to the other as a constant object.  I want to generate two types from that mapping: one for keys and one for values.

```ts
const KeyToVal = {
    MyKey1: 'myValue1',
    MyKey2: 'myValue2',
};
```

The keys are easy enough:

```ts
type Keys = keyof typeof KeyToVal;
```

I'm having trouble getting a *compile-time* type for the values.  I thought maybe one of these would work:

```ts
type Values = typeof KeyToVal[Keys];
type Values<K> = K extends Keys ? (typeof KeyToVal)[K] : never;
type Prefix<
    K extends Keys = Keys, 
    U extends { [name: string]: K } = { [name: string]: K }
> = {[V in keyof U]: V}[K];
```

All of these just made `Values` to be `string`.  I also tried adapting the two answers to [How to infer typed mapValues using lookups in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822693/how-to-infer-typed-mapvalues-using-lookups-in-typescript), but either I got my adaptations wrong, or the answers didn't fit my scenario in the first place.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Actually, you should change the `KeyToVal` to the below declaration:

```js
const KeyToVal = {
    MyKey1: 'myValue1',
    MyKey2: 'myValue2',
} as const; // <----- add the <as const> here
```

Then create the keys types:

```js
type Keys = keyof typeof KeyToVal;
```

Now you can create the types of the values:

```js
type ValuesTypes = typeof KeyToVal[Keys];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer whenever we want to have the exact constant types for object value properties as well. Good job Amer :)

Answer (score 395):

The compiler will widen string literal type to `string`, unless some specific conditions are met as explained in github [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8131#issuecomment-211076929) and [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676), or [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) is used for literal value. Const assertions appeared in TypeScript 3.4:

```
const KeyToVal = {
    MyKey1: 'myValue1',
    MyKey2: 'myValue2',
} as const;

type Keys = keyof typeof KeyToVal;
type Values = typeof KeyToVal[Keys]; //  "myValue1" | "myValue2"
```

Prior to 3.4, there was a workaround to get the same effect. To make the compiler infer literal types, you had to pass your object through a function with appropriately crafted generic type parameters, this one seems to do the trick for this case:

```
function t<V extends string, T extends {[key in string]: V}>(o: T): T {return o}
```

The whole purpose of this function is to capture and preserve types to enable type inference, it's entirely useless otherwise, but with it you can have

```
const KeyToVal = t({
    MyKey1: 'myValue1',
    MyKey2: 'myValue2',
});

type Keys = keyof typeof KeyToVal;
type Values = typeof KeyToVal[Keys]; //  "myValue1" | "myValue2"
```

Comment: Perfect.  I had scanned a couple questions that proposed that, but didn't think the compiler would run the function, so I skipped over the solution. *facepalm*

Comment: What about objects inside an array?

Comment: Here is a useful type alias for above:
`export type ObjectValues<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = T[keyof T];`

Then use it like this: `type Values = ObjectValues<typeof KeyToVal>`

Comment: @ado387, this is nice and I used it in my code recently. Cheers for that.

I'm curious if the following has identical effect, or if I'm missing something:

I have this type:
```
export type SocketPayload = {
  "player:ready": { userId: number; boardId: string; color: string };
  "objectives:created": BoardObjectivesDTO[];
```

I want to know the possible keys, so I use 
`export type SocketAction = keyof SocketPayload`

Does 
`export type PossiblePayloadsTwo = SocketPayload[SocketAction]` have the same effect as your `ObjectValues<T extends Record....` code?

Comment: @ado387 I've actually tried both and it seems Typescript is less confident in asserting that properties in the large union type created the way I suggested `SocketPayload[SocketAction]`, leading to the type error "Property [property] is missing in type [large union type]". Still not quite sure why/how Typescript distinguishes between these two approaches but it seems your solution is the better one

Answer (score 18):

You are trying to infer the type from the object (which can have any number of keys/values). You can try to describe the type (or maybe better an interface) first and then infer Kyes and Values like so:

```
type KeyToObjMap = {
  some: "other",
  more: "somemore",
};

type Keys = keyof KeyToObjMap;

type Values = KeyToObjMap[Keys];

let one: Values = "some";
let two: Values = "other";
let three: Keys = "some";
let four: Values = "somemore";
let five: Keys = "fun";
```

And you will have a correct highlight in IDE.

[image: IDE]

Comment: That *almost* works.  Now I need runtime access to `KeyToObjMap`.

Answer (score 6):

Not quite the same, but if you have an array of objects instead of a single object then you can pull out the values of a known property to create a type by doing something like this:

```
const keyToValArray = [
  { value: 'myValue1', label: 'myLabel1' },
  { value: 'myValue2', label: 'myLabel2' }
] as const;
type Keys = typeof keyToValArray[number]['value']; // 'myValue1' | 'myValue2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it may not be related, but for my usecase, I reached this question because I wanted to create a type based on an object or array. So I just thought it may be useful for someone with the same usecase reaching this question to use enums:
You can simply define an enum like this:

```
enum Arrow {
  Up,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right
}
```

You can read more about them [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) and [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-enum).

You can now use this enum as a type:

```
type Props = {
  arrow: Arrow
}

const Component = (props: Props) => {
  switch(props.arrow) {
    case Arrow.Up:
      // go-up
    case Arrow.Down:
      // go-down
    ...
  }

}
```

and you can use it in your components:

```
  <Component arrow={Arrow.top} />
```