# Get all value types of a double-nested object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

My question is similar to [Types from both keys and values of object in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662208/types-from-both-keys-and-values-of-object-in-typescript), but with an additional layer of nesting:

```
interface Outer {
  a: {
    b: number
  },
  c: {
    d: string
  }
}
```

And I'm only looking to retrieve the union type of all values, here `number | string`.

Here's my stab:

```
type Values<T extends Record<string, any>> = T[keyof T]; // From previous SO answer

type InnerValues<
  T extends Record<string, Record<string, any>>,
  K extends keyof T
> = T[K][keyof T[K]];

type All = Values<Outer>;
type In = InnerValues<Outer, keyof Outer>; // expected number|string
```

but I have an error saying `Outer` doesn't have an index type.

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIFdJWQbwFDLJwBcuBhyARqSOgLaXQDc5Avi4QqfhcgCakAzmCigA5h2Ts8rPHjABPAA4oAanAA26CIIA8AFWQQAHpBB9ByAEoQEAeyh9dw0SDEAaIiAUA+H8gBeZH0AbQBrCAU7GGCAXRZ5ZRQASRAQaHUtHV1yQxMzC2tbBycXcU8be0dnEXKvXx93cgBpI1MIc0sIqJj9PH8g0ObY8Mjo4JDh+LlFFWQAQQ0NQORM7T0MLB8WWZSQFdT0qDXszehPbvGzqG3kAHo7tpUESD5kWgZoAB8ytzwgA)

Answer (score 9):

`T[K][keyof T[K]]` will not work because `T[K]` will be a union of all possible values in `T` (well the values specified by `K` anyway) and `keyof T[K]` will probably end up being `never` if the values have no common keys.

The solution is to take each constituent in the union `T[K]` and get its possible values. We can do this using a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

```
interface Outer {
  a: {
    b: number;
  };
  c: {
    d: string;
  };
}

type DistributiveValues<T extends Record<string, any>> = T extends T ? T[keyof T] : never;

type InnerValues<
  T extends Record<keyof T, object>,
  K extends keyof T
> = DistributiveValues<T[K]>;

type In = InnerValues<Outer, keyof Outer>; // is number|string
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIFdJWQbwFDLJwBcuBhyARqSOgLaXQDc5Avi4QqfhcgCakAzmCigA5h2Ts8rPHjABPAA4oAIsGGjKmYADcIANTgAbdBEEAeACrIIAD0gg+g5ACUICAPZQ+FzeIAaIhAFAD5Q5ABeZBt7R2cY5AB+GIBtAGsIBU8YGIBdZBoIfSgWeWUUAEkQEGgjU3MLcliHCCcXdy8fC0zs3Ksgz0oAKw8wUIDyAGlbVvbkXpyYvAjo9X9tMD1DEzNLK1SpvNCyxRVkaqiLmrrdxowsIMXch+gT5AB6D+QNZFoGaAAH38IDEeCAA)

Comment: Would it be possible to make this recursive so it could give you a union of all the non-`Record` leaf value types in an arbitrarily deep nesting of objects? For example, if the property `d` in `Outer` was an object rather than a string.