# Get union types from a specific property of nested object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

My question is similar with [Get all value types of a double-nested object in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014996/get-all-value-types-of-a-double-nested-object-in-typescript)

But the difference is, I want to get union types from the value of a specific property.

```
const tabsEnum = {
  IDCardReview: {
    label: 'ID Card',
    key: '1',
  },
  PrescriptionReview: {
    label: 'Prescription Review',
    key: '2',
  }
} as const;
```

I want to get a union types like `type Key = '1' | '2'`. Which means use the value of the `key` property in the each object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const tabsEnum = {
  IDCardReview: {
    label: 'ID Card',
    key: '1',
  },
  PrescriptionReview: {
    label: 'Prescription Review',
    key: '2',
  }
} as const;

type Tabs = typeof tabsEnum;
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type ValueTabs = ValueOf<Tabs>;
type K = ValueTabs['key'];
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCGAjCBRMBXAtjAvDA3gFAwwCSAIgMLwBOAJgEoCmAbgJZMDuAXAcSTAA2SJoN4ByCjGr1xAGn4kA1kwCeEgIzz+AXwUkACjSYRgNNgAcobcM3ZdeRAUJFiY4oybOXr4GHY5ObWcVdXcAJmCYHUIdGHgIGFBIKABuQkIoVQsmGAAVJES8LJyQADM4QrQsdJLcgDV4QXQmAHkygB48gD5cfIBtUPL8gF1a7IamloLkPsbmts6ZiG7xnJgAaTmppmX+8VDxMaA)