# Is it possible to declare a dynamic interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently translating my style solution based on `jss` to `typescript` and I've stumble in the following situation.

Consider my basic setup

```
import { useStyles } from './styles'

const styles = theme =>({
    root : { color: 'white' },
    foo : { backgroundColor: 'red' },
})

const Component = () =>{
    const classes = useStyles(styles)

    return <div className={classes.root} />
}
```

You pass a style's object to `useStyles` and the returned value is an object which contains all keys declared inside `styles`. So my `classes` object looks like this

```
{
    root : 'random-name123',
    foo : 'random-name124'
}
```

Since I can't possibly know which keys `styles` will have, my current interface for `classes` is just a dictionary

```
interface Classes {
    [index: string]: string
}
```

My question is:

Can I declare an `interface` in such a way that all keys passed to `styles` are declared as being part of `Classes`? So that when I type `classes.` I would be able to see all possible keys for `classes`?

In other words, I want the keys which compose `Classes` to be predictable. So that if I pass a `styles` objects like this

```
{
    foo : {/*...*/},
    bar: {/*...*/}
}
```

My `Classes` interface would look like

```
{
    foo : string,
    bar : string
}
```

Comment: Could you edit the above code to constitute a [mcve] so that someone can drop it into an IDE and give you an answer they can test first?  Right now my *guess* is that you want `useStyles` to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function whose output type is dependent on its input type.  But without usable example code I don't know if that is what you really want.  Good luck!

Comment: Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtX2QGcQBlDATwhEIB4AVAPgAoAPALnlY6lXIEp4AXgbw6fDgG94AbQDS8LPgDWIcjkSiAuh0IYYigObwAvgG4AUObB5d8XZWpDOGABYgAtiG68BwzhPN4IPgYHBwMSXhrCBwYDgByAHcXLAwQeJMAGkDgxDDIgCMoMCUDULRgAGEcGLj4eLhgDONs4z5La1RbavcABzwQVAwnJl8RAOCom2HIKEJiQiciUgoqQiZ7Nb4LSdn56gA6PJxTeAB6M7s9QxygvYWD0PDTi6v9VANbqOh9wgPksK9QgvS4gGChGCZeAAIgBOCB0PgqHC8AAblAIFhgPAVORzMYgA) maybe?  But I don't know what `useStyles` actually does so I don't know if that signature will fit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interface type check with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript)

Comment: @jcalz Problem is that I have a LOT of boilerplate code to reproduce in sandbox. I've updated the question. That helps? Case isn't enought I'll try to reproduce it in a sandbox

Comment: I'd assume you could make a toy version of `useStyles()` that demonstrates your issue without having to migrate a lot of boilerplate code.    I mean, it could be [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAsIFsUG8BQyRyA7ugPYDSI5JAzgFzJ1hSgDmA3PgL74LkQLZuRwZsEJuJzIAvMlykK1Wo2QAiCiQAmAT3XIe3GAFcQCMMEHITdCAGUwugDYQ6ACgQAjJu4AeUpg4AJRyAHzIcCC6oQTEyAJCYMgAbnDOcgle7nSiENIQwdzxicJQEGBMigDaANZMLGwg7AC6Dawchpm4RoTEAPJeAFYQFgB0tRC6HmnOwWMw5FAAoojo7rXhyOVgdS2ZAFL2-QByY40cwDC67rN7wUV9RDsmUCDbFdx8peSuY87kdjuWwOJyuDzuUKyCLuRRwKrIHwadBYLAGHiGB7BfBAA) for all I know.

Comment: Check this guy: https://github.com/mrmckeb/typescript-plugin-css-modules

Comment: This is indeed interesting. But I'm not using css.

Comment: I'll reproduce in a sandbox @jcalz

Comment: @Dupocas is my answer valid or I misunderstood?

Comment: Both answers helped me. I'm still having some issues but not related to the scope of the question. I'm just waiting a little bit to accept one. Hoping that you can get more upvotes hahah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is what you meant:

```js
const styles = {
  root: 'value1',
  foo: 'value2'
};

type stylesType = typeof styles;

interface Classes extends stylesType {
  [x: string]: string;
}
```

Now when an object is typed as Classes it will have the keys `root` and `foo`.

Inspired by [Types from both keys and values of object in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662208/types-from-both-keys-and-values-of-object-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

In Typescript, you can use the `Record` utility type to map a union of types to another type in a dictionary.

To get all keys of a defined object, you can use `keyof typeof object`, which would give you `"root" | "foo"` in your case.

So, if you want to map all keys to strings, use:

```js
type Classes = Record<keyof typeof styles, string>
```