# Typescript: Use object values as keys for a new type

Tags: typescript, object, types

I have an Object:

```
export const CODES = {
   ALPHA: 'alpha',
   OMEGA: 'omega',
}
```

I want to have a new type which should look like:

```
export type CODES_OBJECTS = {
 alpha: {},
 omega: {}
}
```

But obviously since CODES can be changed in the future and get more key-value pairs, I would like to create a general type, which would automatically get all values from CODES as keys.
I found this [Types from both keys and values of object in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662208/types-from-both-keys-and-values-of-object-in-typescript) but the solution did not work for my case.

Also if its easier CODES also can be enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an indexed access type combined with `keyof` to get what you want.

#### Code

```
type ValuesAsKeys<T extends Record<any, PropertyKey>, NewValue> = Record<T[keyof T], NewValue>

export const CODES = {
   ALPHA: 'alpha',
   OMEGA: 'omega',
} as const;

export type CODES_OBJECTS = ValuesAsKeys<typeof CODES, {}>
/* resolves to type CODES_OBJECTS = {
    alpha: {};
    omega: {};
} */
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/oN9d7w)

#### Explanation

The type `ValuesAsKeys` takes two generics -- `T` is the object whose values we want to use as keys (your `CODES` const) and `NewValue` is the value that we want to assign to those keys (here it's an empty object `{}` but you probably want something better).

In order to use the values of `T` as keys, we have to insist that the values of `T` are something that can be used as a key.  We do that with `T extends Record<any, PropertyKey>` which uses the built-in type `PropertyKey`.

We can access the union of all values of `T` with `T[keyof T]` which is an indexed access type.  We want to create a `Record` where those are the new keys.  So we get `Record<T[keyof T], NewValue>`.

In order for typescript to see `alpha` and `omega` as their literal values and not just `string`, we use `as const` when creating `CODES`.

`CODES` is a value rather than a type, so we use `typeof CODES` as `T`.

#### Enum Version

The typescript is almost identical if using an `enum`.  The only difference is that you don't need to add `as const`.

```
type ValuesAsKeys<T extends Record<any, PropertyKey>, NewValue> = Record<T[keyof T], NewValue>

enum CODES {
   ALPHA = 'alpha',
   OMEGA = 'omega',
}

export type CODES_OBJECTS = ValuesAsKeys<typeof CODES, {}>
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Lw60Dm)