# Create Type using object's value

Tags: typescript

Whit an object like this

```
const USER_EVENT = {
    pageview: 'Visit',
    order: 'Order'
}
```

if I would to get a type with union of all keys

```
type UserEventKey = 'pageview' | 'order'
```

I could do this

```
type UserEventKey = keyof typeof USER_EVENT
```

...but is it possible to get this type with union of all values?

```
type UserEventName = 'Visit' | 'Order'


type UserEventName = ???? is it possibile?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Types from both keys and values of object in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662208/types-from-both-keys-and-values-of-object-in-typescript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use your `USER_EVENT` object as written.  The compiler uses some heuristics to infer the types of variables that are not [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables).  Generally speaking, the compiler sees string property values as being of type `string`:

```
const OOPS_USER_EVENT = {
    pageview: 'Visit',
    order: 'Order'
}
/* const OOPS_USER_EVENT: {
    pageview: string;
    order: string;
} */
```

So the compiler has forgotten about the specific `"Visit"` and `"Order"` values, and nothing you do with `typeof USER_EVENT` will bring them back.

Instead you need to define `USER_EVENT` differently.  The easiest way to do that is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to hint that your object won't change at all, and to ask the compiler to infer the most specific type it can:

```
const USER_EVENT = {
    pageview: 'Visit',
    order: 'Order'
} as const;
/* const USER_EVENT: {
    readonly pageview: "Visit";
    readonly order: "Order";
} */
```

Now `USER_EVENT` has properties of the [`string` literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"Visit"` and `"Order"`;  the information you care about is still there.

---

At this point you need to take an object type like `T` and get the union of property value types instead of the keys.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript) for a more canonial version of this question and its answer.

You can use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) of the form `T[K]` to get the property value types at keys of type `K`. If you want all keys, then `T[keyof T]` works:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];


type UserEventName = ValueOf<typeof USER_EVENT>;
// type UserEventName = "Visit" | "Order"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA8nACgZQPoFVkFEBKqsBqWAcgCowC8MA3gFAwMwAOAhgOYCmAbgJYcDuALhgByAjwg8oIgDT1GIAE4ATDouEi4KtSNoBfWgHoAVDFCRYCFBmx5CJUsLqNm7bnyExoinmDYBueQYlVXUvKB8-QL0YY0NaWnNoGExcfCIyShog105eAQ1xSWk5FxC1DS1Q3RiWCDNwaECTBosU23SHJxzFDhZlcAAbAE9c9wKYACIiqUnAl17+odHysMmqtTn9WPjaKGGmDhgCFkGAVw44ADMAHlIAPizSAG0Aaw5hkCuYUgBdQIS+0OKQgaiwXA4YCgxBYAFsjlQTudLrcgRwvu00vYyPdmoYYGiQWCIVCYfCstMJLMYAAfKYbRSTIA)

Answer (score 5):

Just index the type by it's own keys to get a union of the values.

```
const USER_EVENT = {
    pageview: 'Visit',
    order: 'Order'
} as const

type UserEventName = typeof USER_EVENT[keyof typeof USER_EVENT] // "Visit" | "Order"
```

Note the `as const` there. This is required to force the type to be inferred as specific strings, and not just `string`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAqgZQKICUD6SBqSByAVGAXhgG8AoGSmABwEMBzAUwDcBLRgdwC4YByTVhFZReAGgpUQAJwAmjKT14B5WfN5kAvjFoQYoSFDJkoAT2qN4EeUmaMwUHLQC2F4qfMgAZvGTosuPABtAGtGEy8Yd0YIxFQMbHwAXTIgA)