# Get union codec from type values in io-ts

Tags: typescript, types, dynamic-typing, io-ts-library

I am trying to create union codec from type codec in io-ts.
What I am trying to achieve is basically transforming from:

```
import * as t from 'io-ts'

const FilterTypeC = t.type({
        POTATO: t.literal('POTATO'),
        CABBAGE: t.literal('CABBAGE'),
        BANANA: t.literal('BANANA'),
        TOMATO: t.literal('TOMATO'),
    });
```

into:

```
const FilterTypeUnionC = t.union([t.literal('POTATO'), t.literal('CABBAGE'), t.literal('BANANA'), t.literal('TOMATO')])
```

Is there some kind way for that in io-ts? I tried adapating [similar typescript example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662208/types-from-both-keys-and-values-of-object-in-typescript) but without success.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for, you have a `TypeC` codec already, and are trying to create a new codec that checks for the union of the possible values of that base codec? The TypeScript type you're looking for would be something like this?

```
type valuesOfCodec<T> = t.Type<T[keyof T>, T[keyof T], unknown>;
```

where the codec would decode the values of the given interface.

I don't think that `io-ts` supports this out of the box, but I was able to write a quick function to create a codec given a `TypeC`.

```
// This helper is needed because `t.union` expects at least two codecs
function hasAtLeastTwoItems<T>(t: T[]): t is [T, T, ...T[]] {
  return t.length > 1;
}

// This is the main helper which pulls the value codecs out of a t.TypeC
function valuesOf<T extends t.Props>(
  type: t.TypeC<T>
): t.Type<t.TypeOfProps<T>[keyof T], t.TypeOfProps<T>[keyof T], unknown> {
  const valueCodecs: t.Mixed[] = [];

  for (const key of Object.keys(type.props)) {
    // Grab all of the value codecs out of the iterable properties of the
    // input type's `props` field.
    valueCodecs.push(type.props[key]);
  }

  // If the original type has at least two fields, we can make a union
  // out of the values.
  if (hasAtLeastTwoItems(valueCodecs)) {
    return t.union(valueCodecs);
  }
  // If the type has one field, then the value codec will just be that
  // fields codec.
  if (isNonEmpty(valueCodecs)) {
    return valueCodecs[0];
  }

  // If the type has no fields, then we shouldn't really be decoding
  // successfully at all so I just threw together this `t.Type` that
  // never succeeds at decoding.
  return new t.Type<unknown, unknown, unknown>(
    "always fail",
    (x): x is unknown => false,
    (i, c) => t.failure(i, c, "Cannot decode this codec"),
    (i) => i
  );
}

const FilterUnionTypeC = valuesOf(FilterTypeC);
console.log(FilterUnionTypeC.decode("POTATO")); // -> Right<...>
```

This should do the trick, but I would warn slightly that this is relying on special meta data present on the `t.TypeC` class so this won't work with other codecs even if the `A` type is a record / interface.