# Shorthand for union of all properties of type

Tags: typescript

Context: I'm making function that accepting `const` asserted argument:

```
function langs<T extends Partial<Record<Lang, LangDict>>>(dict: T & Record<keyof T, UnionToIntersection<UnConst<T[keyof T]>>>) {
    return () => dict[lang() as keyof T];
}
```

So I will able to see missing properties in my i18n dictionary:

```
const t = langs({
    ru: {
        title: (name) => `Привет ${name}`,
        placeholder: 'Введите текст',
    },
    en: {
        title: (name) => `Hello, ${name}`,
        placeholder: 'Write text',
    },
} as const);
```

[image]

I need to create union of all types that are properties of parent type:

```
type Lang = 'en' | 'ru' | 'de' | 'zh' | ...etc
type Dict = Partial<Record<Lang, LangDict>>;

type UnConst<T> = { [P in keyof T]:
    T[P] extends string ? string : T[P] extends ((...args: string[]) => string) ? ((...args: string[]) => string) : UnConst<T[P]>
};

type Intersection = UnConst<Dict['ru']> & UnConst<Dict['en']> & UnConst<Dict['zh']> // ...a lot of types here
```

But I don't want to handle in manually. As I see, `UnConst<Dict[Lang]>` is not the same as `UnConst<Dict['ru']> & UnConst<Dict['en']> & UnConst<Dict['zh']> & ...`
Is there shorthand to get same type as: `Intersection` without manual intersecting all keys?
Full example: https://tsplay.dev/w65jEW

Comment: It's that just going to be `LangDict | undefined`? All of the keys have the same value type.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oops I need better example. Let me clarify that

Comment: _(But the short answer is probably `Dict[keyof Dict];`, per e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/53662208/3001761)_

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added context, thank you for pointing me

Comment: Now it's just `UnConst<LangDict> | undefined`, or `UnConst<Dict[keyof Dict]>`, or `UnConst<Dict[Lang]>` - as I see, in e.g. https://tsplay.dev/N9Er8N, they _are_ the same.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added example: https://tsplay.dev/w65jEW
As you can see they aren't working in same way

Comment: I am so confused.  Since `UnConst` is a mapped type, then `UnConst<A | B>` would be `UnConst<A> | UnConst<B>`, not `UnConst<A> & UnConst<B>`, so I'm not sure where you'd expect an intersection to show up.  But there's so much else happening that I don't even know where to start... if you have a type `T` missing one of the keys in `Lang` then `T[K]` for that `K` is going to be `unknown`, and you'll have `UnConst<unknown>` in there which is likely to do crazy things.  If you're trying to solve the "missing properties" issue, why not ask the question directly about that? Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the problem:

```
UnConst<T[Lang]>
```

is actually

```
UnConst<A | Union | Here>
```

What you actually want is this:

```
UnConst<A> | UnConst<Union> | UnConst<Here>
```

because if you have this union, you can turn it into an intersection with this type:

```
// legendary holy grail of typescript developers
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never;
```

which would result in the desired

```
UnConst<A> & UnConst<Union> & UnConst<Here>
```

So how do we do this? We can use distributive conditional types. Let's define a type that takes a dictionary:

```
type AllLangs<T extends Partial<Record<Lang, LangDict>, ...
```

Then we store `Lang` in a generic named `L` so we can use it later in the distributive conditional:

```
type AllLangs<T extends Partial<Record<Lang, LangDict>>, L extends Lang = Lang> = ...
```

Finally, we do the magic:

```
type AllLangs<T extends Partial<Record<Lang, LangDict>>, L extends Lang = Lang> = L extends L ? UnConst<T[L]> : never;
```

But this is just the union, so we wrap that in `UnionToIntersection` to finish the job:

```
type AllLangs<T extends Partial<Record<Lang, LangDict>>, L extends Lang = Lang> = UnionToIntersection<L extends L ? UnConst<T[L]> : never>;
```

You can read a little more about distributive conditional types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

After we have our type that creates the desired result, we just need to use it:

```
export function langsAuto<T extends Partial<Record<Lang, LangDict>>>(dict: T & Record<keyof T, AllLangs<T>>) {
    return () => dict[lang() as keyof T];
}
```

And as you can see in the playground, I think it works just like the manual one:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgQzAcwK4OQUwjAvDAbQHIAnVIgGhiMzEuoC8ALIgXRgR1EigG4AoKAE8ADphgAZJMjwxhYkADN409FggEwqALYAjTCVYDBo8QFUwAYXDQAPABUAfLIDehAAowAlmBgBrTCElGHtWAC5+AEh7And2TAAPKFoAExxoEh8ZAH4YDKyYMJDY+KTUnAAKCoA6WoQSZAgi-JQCVgBKPGcW5E7cqtrq+sbmqEzWjq68sazOootrHgcSx34AX2MfZJJFBGBxKRQAES9gWETksDSYACVMUBIU2x6qHpgAHxgAMVQwM69wB9JNITmdnG41vx+NxoCoULIKp1cM5SORjIkRCASLBFL9-oDECgIABBVBQEAOGAXcowdz1KBeBBwWx3B5PQ7IKgc0FQRx8iopU5QIr2GAAMlu9yxTwCQWU9ioxLgcA5EAcfM6LiiJEwUFQJF8iKmgrOBEJyCNnH8gWCoQEkP4GKxOLxDIJ0ggAFkkOhmaLqVccHTsYzmazpbYOVyQUK+Y4BUKReLJWzbLLbVQFjYoMtUWxnBKs0sYjQ6KwCzAi3YS8x845NdrdfrDUjnCaoGbpJacOn5UZ1lCAPQAKhg2iEHBSgrdkBgw8HQ8H8EwWCu9QnTBAcAnyBICC8cBgwXk2GAmREsBSmAAbpg4CAxCQICYxJWwACwPYQABJMDbCD3DOthmM4+AVGYVJlIGHBgBO-R+PM7TIteIBeCkhQwGAN4GJ0AbXFUCHeGAigGDA35IY4KFoX0ZEYVht4kMYJ4wEqKoepSeFBvSoYslKjyRtI0bHLGjhcpBlzXBysgcqBb4fl+v7-oBH6RuJNISDAuRVjmMQSOWdHYSQjjGCOVJXGOE4IFOXgzjg85QjCsDaD6TKyOaXouXAFRapEZBFD5kQMlAcCYEUFRgAg2ihdM4y9FMAAGgD4IIAAiCABwggBMIIArCCAEIgMAACQuBFUVrPFFBRJEIiIPsm5wFeJBFEQgBIIFlgAsIKl2WZTAHWAFwggCCINllBRGsZWRLQ-nlUFIVhUV0U9K2MDxQAEne95UAVM0lSNkSDkulV7JgNV1Q1ADqmTJHIFyDZEw3rBwXDZu0xiORwZIgG5HqkuS3naqg42RIFNlTTA4WRbNMwoPNSVpVluXraDm3lXt1Vbkd1DNZlbUdV1mV9QNI03aNYB-QDwXRSDUWjLFkPLcqIBrYV8OleVO0wEjB0owYJ1neIyRJFdN1rHdMCOY9QA)