# Extract the union type from the values of an interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to have a type transformer which discards the keys of an interface and creates the union type of the value types of the interface. For instance here is an interface, `Dog`, and the extracted type `DogProperties`:

```
interface Dog {
  name: string
  birth: number
}

type DogProperties = ValueType<typeof dog> // DogProperties = string | number
```

How can I achieve the type transformer `ValueType`? I'm under the impression that it'll require using `keyof`, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually simple:

```
export type ValueType<T> = T[keyof T]
```

I found it in the answers to [Types from both keys and values of object in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662208/types-from-both-keys-and-values-of-object-in-typescript)